# What experiments can distinguish between mixed and pure states?

Tags: density-matrix, decoherence, experimental-realization

To distinguish between a coherent and de-cohered stage of the same system
what experiments can provide the answer? The term Experiment is used here in the Bohr-Einstein-debate sense, a  realizable physically sensible procedure, not necessarily practical in current labs.

Assumptions: Suppose the system initially is in a true superposition state `|ψ⟩ = 1/√2(|0⟩+|1⟩)`, thus its density matrix initially has coherences (off diagonal) terms.

Also assume that If we decide to switch-on an external auxiliary apparatus, and bring it into interaction with our system then, due to the interaction with that auxiliary apparatus its density matrix becomes
\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.5\end{bmatrix} We'll call that new stage 'the system has decohered'.

The question is - what experimental test can determine whether the system has decohered or not.

(*As the model-system any convenient physical 2- state model can be used i.e. spins, energy levels etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to distinguish the state $| + \rangle \langle  + | $ from the dephased state $\frac{1}{2}(| 0 \rangle \langle  0 | + | 1 \rangle \langle  1 | ) = \frac{\mathbb{I}}{2}$.

Here's a simple experiment: apply a Hadamard to both states and then measure in the $\sigma_{z}$ basis. For the ``true superposition'', this transforms it into the state $| 0 \rangle \langle  0 | $ and so we get the output $0$ with probability 1 (when measured in the $\sigma_{z}$ basis). The mixed state on the other hand is unitarily invariant and therefore yields probabilities $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ in *any* basis (inclusing the $\sigma_{z}$ basis).

Update: This process can be generalized to other states and bases -- the idea is to transform to a basis where the coherence in the pure state manifests itself (while the incoherent state transforms into something else; allowing them to be distinguished).

Comment: @MusashiK Algebraically, you want to know the trace of \rho^2. Where \rho is the density matrix. For a pure state the value will be 1, for a mixed state it will be less than one.  For mixed state in this case, \rho^2 = 1/4 * (|0><0|  + |1><1|) . The trace is 1/2.

Comment: @QurakNerd Is it possible to formulate Experiment that measures $Tr(\rho^2)$ ?

Comment: @keisuke.akira Thank you very much for the answer. You have provided two methods - a specific for the concrete mixture, and a general suggestion.Your solution of the specific case utilized the specific property of THIS particular decohered -dephased st. - namely that being a multiple of unit matrix it is invariant. Following your suggestion - dephased states are (only) diagonal in some basis, so what is the common property that would DISTINGUISH them algebraically? I want to stress, that I ask as an appreciation of your solution, and suggestion (not in any other sense)

Comment: #1: I'll give two answers: the general way to distinguish two states and the specific case where one of them is decohered. In the most general case, one would need to do [quantum state tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography) -- that is, measure the state in many different bases and then (experimentally) reconstruct the states to find that they are indeed different. For example, given two qubit states $\rho, \sigma$, to distinguish them, you'd need to measure them in the bases $\sigma_{x}, \sigma_{y}, \sigma_{z}$ and then you can distinguish *any* two different states.

Comment: #2: In the specific case where you know that one of the states is decohered, things can simplify a bit (for example, in the original question). What is the difference between a dephased state and one with off-diagonal elements? This is what is called [quantum coherence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02439). Given a fixed basis (for example, the $\sigma_{z}$ basis for a single qubit), all states that are diagonal in this basis are called ``incoherent'' states, while those that are not diagonal are called coherent states.

Comment: #3: Note that, since density matrices are hermitian, *every* density matrix is diagonal in *some* basis -- but the question here is, whether, given a fixed basis, some state is diagonal in *this* basis or not. Then, one can either compute various coherence measures (like relative entropy of coherence) on these states and then distinguish them. Or, for a more experimental approach, one can measure them in the diagonal basis and a basis which is [mutually unbiased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases) with respect to it.

Comment: #4: These two bases should, in general, be sufficient to distinguish a dephased state from a non-dephased one (as an example, in the original question, we have that the $\sigma_{z}$ and $\sigma_{x}$ eigenbases are mutually unbiased and we use the Hadamard operator to go from one to the other). You're welcome to ask more specific questions if you'd like :)

Comment: Also, in response to @QurakNerd's comment: yes, you can [experimentally measure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212479/how-to-we-measure-quantum-purity-experimentally) $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho^2)$, which is called the [purity of a quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)). However, purity cannot always distinguish a dephased state from a state with non-zero off-diagonal terms -- in general, one would need to make measurements, etc., along the lines of my comment above.

Comment: Also, @MusashiK, if you're satisfied with this answer then please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thank you and Have accepted the answer. Was not aware of this action - as this was my 1-st question. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%88%9D%E5%BF%83

Comment: @keisuke.akira The path of knowledge to [measuring](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.170401) and quantifying [coherence](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.89.041003) indicated in answer 2 is enlightening and wide.

Comment: @MusashiK Thanks, glad I could help :)